# Ramda in angular to get to nested path

Tags: ramda.js

I am new to Ramda and have the follwing problem...I have a json file as follows

```
{
"name": "Alarms",   
"props": {
    "filterPropertyName": {
        "value": "CompositeDataTypeName"
    },
    "children": {
        "collection": [{
            "name": "Adjustment Proximity Switch Failure Alarm",
            "parent": {
                "propName": "Children",
                "propType": "c",
                      ........
```

I used

```
notificationKeys = r.pipe(r.view(r.lensPath([entitiesSelectorName, 'alarms'])), r.keys);
```

to get "name": "Adjustment Proximity Switch Failure Alarm",

If sometimes the json files come as follows,

```
{
"name": "Alarms",
"props": {
    "filterPropertyName": {
        "value": "CompositeDataTypeName"
    },
    "children": {
        "collection": [{
            "name": "Alarm Bits Dint01",
            "parent": {
                "propName": "Children",
                "propType": "c",
                "hidden": true
            },
            "props": {
                "bits": {
                    "collection": [{
                        "name": "BELT SLIP ALARM",
                        "parent": {
                            "propName": "Bits",
                            "propType": "c",
                            "hidden": false
                        },
                        "type.........
```

The notificationKeys gets me to "name": "Alarm Bits Dint01"....how can I get to "name": "BELT SLIP ALARM",

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your overall data structure is not clear to me, nor how you could get the result you did in the first case.  Is this a deeply nested recursive structure?  That is, are there nested collections many levels deep?  If so, how do you know when to check `props.children.collection` versus `props.bits.collection`?  If not, then you should be able to just extend the path supplied to `lensPath` to something like `['props', 'children', 'collection', 0, 'props', 'bits', 'collection', 0, 'name']`, although that gets somewhat unwieldy.  But if so, then there is more work needed.

Comment: Did you have any more details about your requirements to share?